# Getting OSError: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, python, arm

I am trying to access the models/tf.py from the [Yolov5 repository](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) with the following command on my Raspberry Pi 4 and getting the following error:

Command ran:

```
python3 models/tf.py --weights yolov5s.pt --cfg yolov5s.yaml
```

Error:

```
OSError: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try pre-loading the library, i.e.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so python3 models/tf.py --weights yolov5s.pt --cfg yolov5s.yaml
```

The underlying [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1722181) is already fixed, but it may take a while until the fix makes it to the Pi.